# How to install custom folders and jars from non-maven project into maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have been trying to install/use a non-maven project as a dependency to my maven project. I was able to get it installed following this guide I have found - [here](https://gist.github.com/mnadeem/3dbb3f3d23d46e81d995a7f3bf2b208e)

However, my non-maven jar only partially works in my maven project. Reason being it is unable to read its conf/ and its custom lib/ (which contains other jars) folders.

The folder structure of the non-maven project is as follows:

```
|-- non-maven-proj
|--|-- conf/
|--|-- lib/
|--|-- src/
|--|-- target/
```

And so, are they any ways in which I can configure my maven project pom.xml such that it will copies/ install the non-maven-project conf/ and lib/ into the maven project target/ folder upon build?

Below is the folder structure I am trying to achieve.
PS. The lib/ folder is suppose to contain all the jars that the maven project is using alongside with the jars that were used in the non-maven-project too.

```
|-- maven-project
|--|-- src/
|--|-- target/
|--|--|-- conf/
|--|--|-- lib/
```

I have tried looking for ways to do it but unable to find any results.

Appreciate in advance for any advices.

Comment: Are the conf and lib folders packed into the non-maven jar? Does the non-maven jars META-INF/MANIFEST.MF include references to these locations in the jar.

Comment: @JohnWilliams There are contents in the said MANIFEST.MF, however while they are about some of the jars, but none explicitly pointed them to the said folders

Comment: The references to sub-dependency jars needs to be in MANIFEST.MF and these jars need to be META-INF/lib for Java to access them. Perhaps maven-dependency-plugin and the dependency:copy mojo suggested by BIll's answer below does this.

Answer (score 1):

This is done using the `maven-dependency-plugin` and the `dependency:copy` mojo.

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html#dependency-copy